# Server Identify the state of android app

Tags: php, android, server

I have created a **slim api** which updates the status 0 or 1 on a **DB** as I am calling the api with **status** value. I have toggle button **offline/online** which will call the api to update status as

> 1 for Online
>
> 0 for Offline

Now I have created service for ***appkilled*** which will update the status for app **close** since onDestroy wasn't updating the status so this is done.

Also, I have restricted the user to open the app only if there is internet connection else the app will not open and displaying toast message

> **"No Internet Connection"**

But now I am stuck in a Test Case. Tell me Explain two Scenario :

1. Suppose I Have my activity open but I open the notification menu and disconnect internet(wifi , mobile data,etc) or my internet pack finishes.
2. My mobile gets switched off due to battery completely depleted.

Now in both cases the server still has ***online*** status but within the app I am ***offline***.

What to do ? How to resolve it?
If you know the solution please elaborate and provide some link/'s.

Comment: you are not using any type of `real time service` like `socket.io` or `ionic.io` . I mean  `push notification`

Comment: @AabirHussain Nope how to use it and which one?